# GO JS Undo Showing Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, gojs

Salaamun Alekum

While I Am Using [GOJS](http://gojs.net/) [Undo](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/CommandHandler.html#undo) Operation Using Command Of My Code

```
diag.commandHandler.undo();
```

It Is Showing Me Following Mentioned Error In Console Of Browser

> property set error: Error: Picture.element must be an instance of
>   Image, Canvas, or Video.

And After Using Undo When I Use Redo `diag.commandHandler.redo();` Function 
Then Nodes Data Array `diagram.model.nodeDataArray;` Gives Null

Can Anyone Identify What Could Be The Root Cause

Thank You

Comment: do you have `canUndo()` set to true at the object.

Comment: http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/UndoManager.html#undo

Comment: Reverse the effects of the transactionToUndo. canUndo must be true for this method to have any effect.

This is called by CommandHandler.undo.

This will raise a "StartingUndo" ChangedEvent of type ChangedEvent.Transaction, perform the Transaction.undo on the transactionToUndo, and then raise a "FinishedUndo" ChangedEvent of type ChangedEvent.Transaction. The two ChangedEvents are to let model listeners know that an undo is about to take place and that it just finished. isUndoingRedoing will temporarily be set to true during this operation.

Comment: Thank You @Jai But How To Set It True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in the library, which is fixed in version 1.5.14.

Thanks for reporting the bug.